# Custom string to 128-bit string

Tags: c#, 128-bit

I am trying to force a custom string with a length between 0 and 15 to a 128-bit string, so I can use it as a `AesCryptoServiceProvider` key.

I have tried fiddling around with multiple strategies, and have ended up with the following:

```
        if (stringToConvert.Length > 16)
        {
            StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
            char[] chA = stringToConvert.ToCharArray();
            int chAMaxLength = chA.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (i <= chAMaxLength)
                {
                    sB.Append(chA[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I need a string exactly 16 characters long (16*8 = 128).

I am now stuck with it, and just need a helping hand to go through this obsticle.
I apologize in advance if this may seem simple.

Example:
`asd` would become
`asdasdasdasdasda`

Comment: in the end,,, `stringToConvert = sB.ToString();` ??

Comment: The if is never entered as your string to convert is 0 .. 15 chars in length, and is thus not longer than 16.

Comment: If the chA is only 5 characters long, the end result will only be 5 characters.

Comment: I have a feeling you guys dont know about encryption keys, or what I need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    b.Append(stringToConvert[i % stringToConvert.Length]);
}
stringToConvert = b.ToString();
byte[] key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringToConvert);//key size is 16 bytes = 128 bits
```

Even better (without a `StringBuilder`):

```
byte[] key = new byte[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i+=2)
{
    byte[] unicodeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(stringToConvert[i % stringToConvert.Length]);
    Array.Copy(unicodeBytes, 0, key, i, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply calc the hash of your string (and resize it to 16, because SHA1 is 20 bytes)

```
string password = "shortstring";

using (SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    // This is one implementation of the abstract class SHA1.
    byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    Array.Resize(ref result, 16);
}
```

This is still wrong. You should use the Rfc2898 that describe how to strengthen passwords.
In the end the basic principle is to repeatedly call hash functions on the result of previous hash functions.

```
string password = "shortstring";
byte[] salt = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }; // this is fixed... It would be better you used something different for each user

// You can raise 1000 to greater numbers... more cycles = more security. Try
// balancing speed with security.
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pwdGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 1000);

// generate key
byte[] key = pwdGen.GetBytes(16);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I dont need to generate any strength of password. Even `a` would be fine :D I'll definitely keep this in mind for the future.